# PhP Curl SFTP File Editing

Tags: php, html, curl, web, sftp

I am trying to create a online editor for multiple server. I want to edit a custom file on a server and I need to get it via sftp. My current code looks like this:

```
<?php

$user="user";
$pass = 'pass';
$c = curl_init("sftp://$user:$pass@0.0.0.0/path/to/file/file.txt");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PORT, 3206);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
//the next line is not working and from now on am I stuck
$text = file_get_contents($fh);

?>
<!-- HTML form -->
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="text"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($text) ?></textarea>
<input 

type="submit" />
<input type="reset" />
</form>
```

I want to edit this file on the website and then reupload it to the sftp server in the same directory (overweite the existing one). I do not know how to continue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off if it's a file containing some programming language, check ACE.js.
It's simply an incredible JS module for use as a web IDE and it has all the features any programmer looks for in an IDE, it's so good I would ALMOST consider switching to it as my primary IDE.

Then use this PHP code:

```
<?php
  $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
  $filename = 'sftp://user@location/file/name.js';
  //Use SSH public key authentication
  $handle = fopen($filename,'w') or die('Cannot open file: '.$filename);
  $data = $_POST['src'];
  fwrite($handle, $data);
  fclose($handle);
?>
```

and use this JS code to call the PHP script:

```
<script src="../scripts/ace/ace.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  var editor = ace.edit("editor");
  editor.setTheme('<?php echo $theme; ?>');
  editor.getSession().setMode("<?php echo $language; ?>");
  editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
  editor.setReadOnly(true);
  <?php //Save shortcut binding ?>
  editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: 'Save',
    bindKey: {win: 'Ctrl-S',  mac: 'Command-S'},
    exec: function(editor) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", './scripts/save_file.php', true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
      xhr.send(
        JSON.stringify(
            {src:editor.getValue()}
        )
      );
    }
  });
</script>
```